# use feature level tag to determine which scenario should be cleaned up in after_scenario with behave

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-behave

I'm using 'behave' to test my Python application.

I've a set of what I'll call archival tests. I want to run a cleanup on the archive server after any of these are run. I plan to put the cleanup code in my `after_scenario` but I only want it to run for acrhival teses. Is it possible to use an `@archive` tag at feature level and for any scenario in that feature the archive cleanup will run? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `before_tag` and `after_feature` functions to do this:

`features/environment.py`

```
def before_tag(context, tag):
    if tag == 'archive':
        context.archive = True

def after_feature(context, feature):
    if context.archive is True:
        # Cleanup

    context.archive = False
```